# React Hooks "Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm making a to-do list. I want my list items to become line-through when I mark the checkbox. Therefore I am trying to make a const called markComplete. I make use of component drilling by sending my props from component 'TodoItem' to 'Todos' to 'App'.

The problem: In markComplete I try to access `this` because I want to change the state of the list item I checked. Though because I'm using Hooks in this project + the fact that I am kinda new, I struggle to find a solution to the error "Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined". [Link to my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHnWA.png)

So I believe with Hooks, setState() is not really a thing anymore. I think have to make use of `useEffect()` , but I'm not so sure. It might have something to do with binding, but I do bind in 'TodoItem' and I do use arrow functions.

Could anyone have a quick look at my code and tell me what I am missing here?
Thanks in regard.

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Todos from './components/Todos';
import './App.css';

const App = (props) => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState(
    [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Learn React',
        completed: true
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Eat lunch',
        completed: false
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Meet up with friends',
        completed: false
      },
    ]
  );

  const markComplete = (id) => {
    console.log(id);

    this.setState([{todos: this.todos.map(todo => {
      if(todo.id === id) {
        todo.completed =! todo.completed
      }
      return todo;
    })}]);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/* Todos.js is being called. Also props are being passed in Todos.js. */}
      <Todos todos={todos} markComplete={markComplete}/>
    </div>
  );


}

export default App;

  // // Log all todos in objects
  // console.log((todos));

  // // Log the 1st todo object
  // console.log((todos[0]));

  // // Log the title of the first todo
  // console.log((todos[0].title));
```

Todos.js

```
import React from 'react';
import TodoItem from './TodoItem';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

function Todos(props) {
  // console.log(props.todos)

  return (
    <div>
        <h1>My to do list</h1>

        {props.todos.map(todo => { // using props in child component and looping

            return (
                // Outputting all the titles from todo. It is more clean to make a seperate component for this.
                // <li>{todo.title}</li> 

                // Calling a seperate component called ToDoItem in order to return the titles.
                <TodoItem key={todo.id} todo={todo} markComplete={props.markComplete} />
            )
        })}

    </div> 
  );
}

// Defining proptypes for this class. In app.js, we see that Todos component has a prop called 'todos'. That needs to be defined here.
Todos.propTypes = {
  todos: PropTypes.array.isRequired
}

export default Todos;
```

TodoItem.js

```
import React, { useCallback } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

function TodoItem(props) {
    // Change style based on state. 
    // By using useCallback, we can ensure the function App() is only redefined when one of its dependencies changes.
    // In this, case that is the dependencie 'completed'.
    // If you use id / title in the getStyle as well, you have to define these in the useCallback.
    const getStyle = useCallback(() => {  
        return {
            backgroundColor: '#f4f4f4',
            padding: '10px',
            borderBottom: '1px solid #ccc',

            // If-else text decoration based on state
            textDecoration: props.todo.completed ? 
            'line-through' : 'none'
        }
    }, [props.todo.completed]);

    // Destructuring
    const { id, title } = props.todo

    return (
        // Call out a function to change style based on state
        <div style={getStyle()}>
            <p> 
                { /* Start of ladder: passing the state though to Todos.js */ }
                { /* We use bind to see which checkbox is being marked. We use id to make this distinction.  */ }
                <input type="checkbox" onChange={props.markComplete.bind(this, id)}
                /> { ' ' }
                { title }
                {props.todo.title}
            </p>
        </div>
    )
}

// Defining proptypes for this class. In Todos.js, we see that TodoItem component has a prop called 'todo'. That needs to be defined here.
TodoItem.propTypes = {
    todo: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

// const itemStyle = {
//     backgroundColor: '#f4f4f4'
// }

export default TodoItem
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use `this.setState` in a functional component which is App. You instead need to use `setTodos` which is the setter for your todos state. Also use the callback approach to update state since your current state is dependent on previous state

```
const markComplete = (id) => {
    console.log(id);

    setTodos(prevTodos => prevTodos.map(todo => {
      if(todo.id === id) {
        todo.completed =! todo.completed
      }
      return todo;
    }));
}
```

Read more about `useState` hook in the **[documentation here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)**

Comment: Just a quick question: if I use the callback approach, the dependency array needs to have 'setTodos' right?

Comment: There is no dependency array to state updater function.

Comment: Oh, then where do I need to implement useCallback?

Comment: You don't need to unless you are looking at performance. And by callback approach we mean the functional version of setTodos

Comment: However if you wanted to ask about useCallback dependency to markComplete. You can pass setTodos or not because it anyways won't change

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I thought useCallback was the way to fix the problem of updating the state. At the moment, the first checkbox I check updates state, but further checkboxes don't update state. Do you perhaps have any idea why this is?

Comment: Could you create a small demo of it and create a new post for it. I am not able to understand you problem fully

Comment: My questions limit is reached ):

Comment: Its weird. I didn't know there is such a policy. You have just asked 6 questions. Anyways not problem. Could you create a small codesandbox and I will have a look at it

Comment: Awesome! I hope this link works: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-breeze-4w64g

Comment: Working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-ritchie-h31pi `setTodos(prevTodos =>
      prevTodos.map(todo => {
        if (todo.id === id) {
          return {
            ...todo,
            completed: !todo.completed
          }
        }
        return todo;
      })
    );` In the setTodo function you were mutating state which causes the issue